# Roboticize an old netbook?

Tags: raspberry-pi, python

I have an old beat-up netbook that is currently collecting dust. I've also only taken stuff apart, without having to worry about putting it back together, so please bear with my possibly stupid questions.

a) I imagine it's possible to wire this baby up to servos, breadboards, and all that good stuff. Am I correct?

b) I'd like to start with some simple Raspberry Pi-like projects (think automating my irrigation system, feeding the dog from work, etc). Obviously barring the energy expenditure, wouldn't a netbook be more apt than a Raspberry Pi for handling this type of thing?

c) I have basic Python experience, but I wouldn't mind picking up more as I go. Would that be sufficient?

Cheers!

Comment: Hi jboneca and welcome to the Robotics SE. It has been suggested that your question be closed as being too broad. You would probably get a better response if you broke your three questions up into different posts. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this can be done, however the important bit isn't really the netbook here. The important bit is the type of interface you decide to use and the command language you code in to control that interface.

Your netbook probably has USB and possibly serial - but you need to have a way to connect these to relays and voltage control devices.

X10 or NexTag produce a range of USB compatible interfaces, and provide a controller language. They provide a very simple, beginner's route to home automation and control.

For more fun, you could build your own serial interface board - which converts the signals from the 9 serial pins to useful output, but this is more of an electronics project - not for the faint hearted :-)

Comment: Thanks @Rory. I assume a netbook is more capable than a Raspberry Pi or Arduino, do you agree?

Comment: Raspberry pi will be possibly better than a netbook, and arduinos may require more work but are optimised for this sort of thing.